# Bitcoins transactions over 1000 confirmations, but amount remains red

Tags: transactions

I'm newbee,

I did several payments about 14 days ago.
There are 618 confirmations, but the amount remains red and nothing happens.
See the example of my blockchain wallet and 4 more examples.
The balance of my blockchain wallet is Zero.
In the other examples i have more then 1000 confirmations and still rising every hour.
What do I wrong ?
[image]

Comment: But my question is, the payments I've done keeps red and nothing happens further after more than 14 days. Some payments are done to my own other wallets, and some paymetns to other persons, but no bitcoins received in my own wallet or in the other persons wallet. How long does it take or when disapear the negative red amounts ? When are the payments exactly done ?

Answer (score 1):

In the "Amount (BTC)" column on the right side of your window, a **red number** means money that you are sending out, and a **black number** means money that you are receiving in.

(The second row should have the amount in red too, but it is in black merely because the row is highlighted/selected with the cursor.)

The transaction pictured in the screenshot is indeed confirmed: txhash [90d43acff8c70d8ad2e8d09a6457b76caafc521501d71b573e9927939df8978c](https://www.blockchain.com/btc/tx/90d43acff8c70d8ad2e8d09a6457b76caafc521501d71b573e9927939df8978c).

Comment: I suspect that this is because the row is highlighted.

Comment: Yes it's because the row is higlighted. But my question is, the payments I've done keeps red and nothing happens further after more than 14 days. Some payments are done to my own other wallets, and some paymetns to other persons, but no bitcoins received in my own wallet or in the other persons wallet. How long does it take ?

Comment: The transaction in the screenshot is indeed confirmed, but when I open the blockchain wallet where I send the bitcoin it's balance is zero. So where are the bitcoins ?

Comment: @RobVanderWielen: First you need to separate between two unrelated things. The payment will always be displayed in red. It's red not because it's unconfirmed, it's red because it's an outgoing payment. All outgoing payments are marked red. Apparently, there's a second issue, that you don't see the funds as being received in the target wallet. You probably should edit this question (or maybe even create a new one) to clarify what the real problem is, and provide the relevant details (addresses, screenshots of the blockchain.info wallet, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Red marks negative balances. Or Am I missing some red somewhere else on the page?

Comment: I did 5 payments and all 5 keeps in red. All 5 have confirmations. My total balance is above zero.

Comment: Right. All 5 are negative amounts of bitcoin for your account, because you sent money somewhere else. Like they're all ["in the red."](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/r/red-ink.asp)